# Unable to connect to Remote Server when we pass credentials as secure string but able to login when we are manually entering the password

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Unable to connect to Remote Server when we pass credentials as secure string but able to login when we are manually entering the password instead of converting into string.

The script i am using as below

```
param(
    
    [string]$ServiceAccount = 'xyz/v-abc',
    [string]$ServiceAccountPassword = '$Kxyz'
)
$pwdSecureString =  $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ServiceAccount, $pwdSecureString
$appServer = 'xyz'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $appServer -ScriptBlock {  Get-service -Name 'WinRM'} -Credential $cred
```

#The error i am facing is below

[xyz] Connecting to remote server xyz failed with the following error message : The user
name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (xyz) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogonFailure,PSSessionStateBroke

#I am able to connect to server when i use below command i.e., entering the password while script execution instead of passing the password as $cred

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $appServer -ScriptBlock {  Get-service -Name 'WinRM'} -Credential xyz

Can you please help us in connecting the remote server using invoke-command by passing the password as securedstring

Comment: Are you running the script with elevated privileges (Run as Admin)? What powershell version do you actually use and please remove the version tags for versions you do not need.

Comment: Yes, i am running the script as admin

Comment: Actually, i am able to connect to remote server when i manually enter the password instead of encrypting

Comment: I do not see where you defined `$password`.. shouldn't you use `$ServiceAccountPassword` instead?

Comment: i mispelled it, I am using the below code only
$pwdSecureString =  $ServiceAccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force

Comment: [abc] Connecting to remote server abc failed with the following error message : The user 
name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (abc:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogonFailure,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: Getting above error when i have encrypted the password, but able to connect to server when i am directly entering the password..
I changed the $ to @ in password and tried .. Now the password .is @Kabc
Still facing the same issue.. I think the issue is in encrypting the password